# 特定のイベントを表示するためにechartsのマークポイントをチャートに追加する方法

Tags: javascript

下図のように、特定のイベントを表示するためにechartsのマークポイントをチャートに追加したいのですが。特定の日付にイベントを追加できることを期待しています。そして、ユーザがイベントブロック(D)にカーソルを置くと、ツールチップで詳細が表示されます。

echartsのマークポイントオプションを使ってイベントブロックを追加しようとしましたが、ホバーイベントにツールチップを表示させる方法がわかりません。また、特定のデータにイベントを追加したいのですが、今は(x, y)で位置を設定するだけです。または、この問題を解決する方法/オプションはありますか？ありがとうございました！

```
markPoint: {
  symbol: 'rect',
  symbolSize: 15,
  label: {
    formatter: 'D',
  },
  itemStyle: {
    color: 'rgba(70,78,86,.9)',
  },
  data: [
    { x: 70, y: 140 },
  ],
},
```

- 実績

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MitaC.png

- 期待結果

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLTzz.png